# google-compute-engine resize disk is now empty and has the wrong OS. Also SSH is broken to the server and three websites are down. How to fix it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, operating-system, resize, missing-data

GCloud resizing of disk resulted in an unusable server. Server doesn't have access to the data from the cloud shell because cloud shell isn't a VM and the port 22 is open but ssh won't work. Disk shows twice as large as it should be and the OS is incorrect.

Comment: Restore from backups?

Comment: Resizing the disk leads to catastrophic failure on google compute engine? Interesting, because it looks like the data is still there, just maybe written twice.                                     Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                             60G   45G   16G  75% /

Comment: It's also interesting that an Ubuntu machine reboots and is now a Debian machine. Pingable but not loading and maybe because the OS is wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Tools are available to read/write that might be considered back door. All three sites are back up. Thanks anyways.